# Multipass change ip range

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ip, multipass

So I have a KVM VM here made with multipass and the IPV4 automatically assigned is not working:

```
computer ip: 192.168.1.71
node ip: 192.168.1.78
  |> vm ip: 192.168.122.28
```

I am trying to connect to the SSH server hosted on the vm via my computer.

Thank you for reading, please let me know.

Comment: Your question title doesn't say what the question is about in the context of every other computer issue possible. Anyways, you can try to ssh from your VM itself... can it VM into itself? If so you ssh server is running... then, can you ping it from outside? If not, then there is no gateway... only hosts on the same subnet can talk directly to each other without a gateway... you can put hosts on the same subnet with bridging. By default VM's are behind NAT, which means they can talk out but nobody can talk in. What you need to do is set up port forwarding, bridging or a gateway.

Comment: @Dagelf yes, I am having the issue you stated with the subnets .

Comment: Could you possibly give me some more info on how to do this with multipass?